# External monitor requires exiting to work on i3wm

Tags: multiple-monitors, i3-wm

I installed i3wm. When I plug the HDMI monitor it does not get connected. I have to exit i3 and log back in for it to work.

Is that normal behaviour? Either case how can I have it working immediately?

Comment: Please know I did not go through the entire website, but I did find this: "For more information on how to use multi-monitor setups, see the i3 User’s Guide.". Perhaps its a local i3wm bug.

Comment: @WillemK I did read the user guide. I found nothing related to my problem. Probably a bug as you said.

Comment: *i3* automatically uses added displays, once they have been configured/activated, but it does not handle the activation on its own.  Have a look at `xrandr` for that. There is also a GUI wrapper called `arandr`.

Comment: @user10853: I can imagine not all hardware responds well if an HDMI monitor gets (dis)connected. I would suggest you only (dis)connect it when the system is down.

Comment: @Adaephon Thanks. That works & I'll be using it though I'd prefer that it gets activated immediately on connecting.

Comment: @WillemK I asked this question because I rarely, unless forced, to logout or shutdown. I usually suspend or lock only.

Comment: I had the same problem and, as already suggested, I use xrandr: `xrandr --output HDMI-2 --auto` Where "HDMI-2" is the name of the output/display I want to activate. You can call `xrandr` without any arguments to see a list of possible outputs. After activation I can change the configuration (--left-of or whatever else needed...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I read the manual of xrandr and I saw interesting commands and properties. 
Generally in your system (if you use a laptop), the output use by the HDMI port is "HDMI-2" and your screen name is "eDP-1".

You can process xrandr for seeing information about screens (name of the output, ...).

```
sudo apt install xrandr

# duplicate your screen
xrandr --output <your_output> --auto

# extand your screen (left "--left-of", right "--right-of", top "--above", down "--below")
xrandr --output <your_output> --auto --right-of <your_screen>
```

PS: you can see all your ouputs with

```
xrandr
```

PS2: It is available on all linux distributions as long as there is the xrandr package